# what does mean "string--" in "https://string--myhtml.netlify.com" which is domain of netlify?

Tags: string, dns, structure, netlify

I deployed some html files through netlify.

Then, clicked production to view some pages.

[production in netlify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx74a.png)

Netlify provided the URL in this form.

`https://6f4b3cf0e9e201172cbc715a--myhtml.netlify.app`

I want to know what means "`6f4b3cf0e9e201172cbc715a--`" before `myhtml.netlify.app`.

Anyone know about that, help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain name is an [atomic deploy domain name](https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/#:%7E:text=deploy%20controls.-,Atomic%20deploy,-1234abcd12acde000111cdef%2D%2Dyoursitename.netlify) or deploy permalink:

> Unique URL for a specific build that is successfully deployed. Also called deploy permalinks or just permalinks. Unlike the other site deploys, the web content at this URL never changes. A new deploy permalink is generated for each successfully deployed build of your site.

So, if you change your HTML files and deploy a new version, you will get a new domain name with a new random identifier, and the old domain name will still point at the old version.

The linked page lists other domain names that get assigned to your site by Netlify, and also has instructions on how to configure your own domains.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I found about that in the official documentation.

https://docs.netlify.com/site-deploys/deploy-previews/#deploy-preview-urls

Thank you again!